# Comparison of hem, browserify, stitch and others

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, browserify, node-stitch

I've seen some node modules that allow compiling CommonJS/Node.js modules for the browser. Until now I've found:

- [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)
- [hem](https://github.com/spine/hem)
- [stitch](https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch)
- [browserbuild](https://github.com/LearnBoost/browserbuild)
- [volo](https://github.com/volojs/volo)
- [cajon](https://github.com/requirejs/cajon)

I am currently using browserify and I noticed some overhead of 300? lines when compiling. Are there any noticeable differences between those tools that should make me switch? Or do you even now some better tools?

Comment: BrowserBuild sounds the most promising.

Comment: @EliranM. Why do you think so?!

Comment: You should add [volo](https://github.com/volojs/volo) and [cajon](https://github.com/requirejs/cajon) to your list.  Cajon is an AMD module loader that supports CommonJS module formats.  Volo is comparable to hem, IMO.

Comment: @rharper Thanks for the additions, they're added.